# Firebase Google Auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Using the very clear simple examples provided ([Firebase Google Auth](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/google.html)) I have been unable to get an authorization from Google. Okay I have, but not consistently meaning I have actually gotten the object back a few times...but if I logout with `ref.unauth()` it will not work again.  Searching high and low I have been unable to find others experiencing anything similar.  I have to be missing something.  I'm really not sure what to share here to give understanding.  This is all I have in the page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Contacts</title>
    <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js'></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        var contactsRef = new Firebase('https://my-notreal-firebaseapp.firebaseio.com/contacts');
        var authData = contactsRef.getAuth();
        
        if (authData) {
          console.log("User " + authData.uid + " is logged in with " + authData.provider);
        } else {
            console.log("User is logged out");
            contactsRef.authWithOAuthRedirect("google", function(error,authData){
                //do stuff post authentication
            },{

                remember: "sessionOnly",
                scope: "email"
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

It redirects back to the login every time.  I have multiple Google accounts so it takes me to the "Choose an account" page actually. I have very simple rules set up as well.

```
    {
    "rules": {
        "contacts":{

              ".read": true,
              ".write": true
        }
      }
    }
```

I double checked to make sure I have everything set up correctly in the Google Developers Console and in the Firebase App Dashboard as well.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: ...and BTW ref.authWithOAuthPopup worked perfectly.  I am pretty sure this issue is related to incorrect handling of the redirect.

Comment: After you return from the page, can you refresh and see if you're logged in?

Comment: @DavidEast just getting back to this...if you refresh it tries to authenticate again.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across this same issue today.  The issue is this (as I understand it): when you use the `authWithRedirect`, your browser redirects away from your web app on its way to Google, effectively blowing it away (including the Firebase reference).

On the round trip from Google, it takes something like 250ms for the Firebase ref to load AND receive authentication information.  So your app loads, but doesn't think it's authenticated, since at the moment the app loads, the Firebase ref is not authenticated yet.

The answer is to add the `onAuth()` Firebase method somewhere in your bootstrapping code.  `onAuth()` will listen for changes in your Firebase ref's status, and can fire one method when it is authenticated, and another method when it is unauthenticated.  I'd give that a whirl and see if that works for you.